# Data annotation error message from external resource file

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am using data annotations for validation. I know about setting "ErrorMessageResourceType" and "ErrorMessageResourceName" while creating class properties.
I have a requirement like, I will be consuming class which is using data annotation for validation, as a class library. But I need to set the resource file in the application which will be consuming the class library. My application will be an asp.net web application.

Comment: If you use multilinguar ressources, I advice you to handle ressources in your web project. Need code to understand yor issue... please add it to the question :-)